# grunt-contrib-jshint throws error against grunt-contrib-handlebars generated templates

Tags: gruntjs, handlebars.js, jshint

I'm trying to precompile my Handlebars templates during my Grunt tasks, then Lint them along with the rest of my JS files. In Grunt I'm using grunt-contrib-jshint and grunt-contrib-handlebars. The Handlebars templates compile just fine (although they look quite a bit different than the results of precompiling via Handlebars Cl).

Here's an example of the template file output by the grunt-contrib-handlebars task:

```
this["JST"]["views/handlebars/foo1.hbs"] = function (Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
  this.compilerInfo = [4,'>= 1.0.0'];
helpers = this.merge(helpers, Handlebars.helpers); data = data || {};
```

However, when the Lint task runs, I get the following error:

> ['JST'] is better written in dot notation.

I've tried adding predef: ["JST"] to my jshint task in Grunt, but that hasn't helped. I also see another solution online for just suppressing that warning, but that solution seems sub-optimal.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Why are you linting precompiled Handlebars templates at all? For me it doesn't has much sense. Linting is a good practice for code you writing by hand, but not for autogenerated code.

Comment: ...uh, because I'm all n00b to sjhint, and not thinking things through. This sounds like the real answer to my situation. Thanks!